# How to show the hidden files and hide the shown files with ls?

Tags: find, xargs, ls, hidden-files

To list files I use `ls`. I know how to list almost (`-A`) or all (`-a`) of them. But when I try to show the hidden files and hide the shown files I'm out of luck with:

```
ls --hide='*' -A
```

The behavior that the `-A` option neutralizes the `--hide` option is described in the documentation of `ls`.

So is there another option to `ls` I could use? The `find`-`xargs`-`ls` combo cannot be the only solution, right?

Comment: I am seeing a total of n files and ls with all modifiers plus find does not show directory contents, that might be a solution for knowing what´s going on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, use:

```
ls -A -I'*'
```

In order to ease my everday command line experience with the `bash` shell I defined the following aliases building on top of each other:

```
alias ls="ls -h --color=auto"
alias lsa="ls -A"
alias lsh="lsa -I'*'"
alias ll="ls -l --time-style=long-iso"
alias lla="ll -A"
alias llh="lla -I'*'"
alias lv="ll -v"
alias lva="lv -A"
alias lvh="lva -I'*'"
alias lt="ll -t"
alias lta="lt -A"
alias lth="lta -I'*'"
alias lr="ll -R"
alias lra="lr -A"
alias lrh="lra -I'*'"
```

Answer (score 0):

To list only the dotfiles but omit `.` and `..` :

```
alias ldot='ls -ld .??*'
```